# How to completely remove UIStatusBar in iOS Application?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I can get the status bar to hide, but the application still respects the height of the bar (see image below). I also need to make sure there's not a 'flicker' of the status bar hiding on initial load since it pushes the nav menu button down and it jumps back up on hide.

Methods I've tried:

Added the following in my main controller. This one flickrs the layout on initial load.

```
// hide the status bar 
ionic.Platform.fullScreen();
```

Set Key, Value pairs in info.plist

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

which equates to:

```
Status bar is initially hidden = YES
View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

Tried using the the [StatusBar plugin](https://github.com/jonathannaguin/org.apache.cordova.statusbar) on load:

```
  .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
       // Hide the status bar
       if(window.StatusBar) {
         StatusBar.hide();
       }
     });
  })
```

Tried setting the following in my MainViewController.m

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

and add new method

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
return YES;
}
```

I've tried about 3 different cordova plugins off of github.

I'm also a web developer, so when providing answers that involve changing obj-c, please explain like I'm 5 :}

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-hide-uistatusbar/4025

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left a comment for you on your post but here's the solution I came up with.

What you can do is install the splash screen pluign

```
 $ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
```

Then do this in your .run function

```
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $timeout) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the status bar
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.hide();
            $timeout(function () {
                window.navigator.splashscreen.hide();
            }, 2500);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Working on an implementation right now, I had two status bar plugins loading. Wondering if that's part of the issue.

Comment: Could be, I know there is to on cordova's plugin repo which has caused some confusion.

Comment: Should I have access to window.StatusBar in my console? even with the plugin installed I'm not getting anything back. Though window.statusbar returns a Object BarProp { visible: true }

Comment: It should be available through `StatusBar` now `window.StatusBar`

Comment: I installed the splashscreen plugin and made sure I had access to StatusBar, the bar disappears but the space is still there. The same as my above screen shot.

Comment: Got it working! Had to use `ionic.Platform.fullScreen();` instead of StatusBar.hide() (though I'm pretty sure it still calls it). Thanks for your help through out these last couple of days! Have to wait 19 hours until I can reward the bounty, I'll hit it up tomorrow :}

Comment: No worries, the important thing is that you got it figured out. See you on the forum

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing prefersStatusBarHidden in your view controller. e.g.

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: That gives me the same result as in the above picture. I need that pink button to sit flush with the top. For some reason the status bar is hidden but it's bounds are still being respected. I even tried absolutely positioning the pink button top left, and it's not an issue on my localhost, only in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

For ios 7 in each view write method :

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden 
{
   return YES;
}
```

And for ios 6 write follwing once in homeview or appdelegate

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `'CDVViewController.m'`, go to

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

and insert the below

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

My CDVViewController.m looks like this,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL* appURL = nil;
    NSString* loadErr = nil;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
.....
```